# How do I set up a loop device at startup with service?

Tags: mount, systemd, services, loop-device

I'm setting up a loop device for VM raw image back-file, with this command:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 "/home/asus/VirtualBox VMs/Windows RAW/Windows 10.img"
```

And it works fine.

```
$ losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                            DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /home/asus/VirtualBox VMs/Windows RAW/Windows 10.img   0     512
```

But I want to make this change permanent, so I created this `.sevice` to run at startup:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/loops-setup.service
[Unit]
Description=Setup loop devices
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target
After=systemd-udev-settle.service
Required=systemd-udev-settle.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/losetup /dev/loop0 "/home/asus/VirtualBox VMs/Windows RAW/Windows 10.img"
ExecStop=/sbin/losetup -d /dev/loop0
TimeoutSec=60
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
Also=systemd-udev-settle.service
```

Also this service starts well manually:

```
sudo systemctl start loops-setup
```

But it failed to start at startup, and shows this error:

```
May 11 19:57:17 ubuntu losetup[308]: losetup: /dev/loop0: failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory
```

I guess its because of hierarchy of services, and I should change `Before` and `After` options but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm going to guess that `systemd-udev-settle.service` is never actually called - I can find no reference to it in my `journalctl` or in `systemd-analyze blame`.  Since your service waits until after....

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thank's for your reply. yes, adding `home.mount` and changing `systemd-udev-settle.service` to `systemd-udevd.service` resolved problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused by two reasons:

**1.** As @CharlesGreen mentioned `systemd-udev-settle.service` can not be activated:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable systemd-udev-settle.service
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

So this service stays inactive:

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-udev-settle.service
● systemd-udev-settle.service - udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udev-settle.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:udev(7)
           man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
```

---

**2.** The second problem is `losetup` command needs to access `home` partition to set up `Windows 10.img`. And this partition is not mounted at startup.

---

Therefore change the service in this way, resolved problem:

```
[Unit]
Description=Setup loop devices
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target
After=systemd-udevd.service home.mount
Required=systemd-udevd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/losetup /dev/loop0 "/home/asus/VirtualBox VMs/Windows RAW/Windows 10.img"
ExecStop=/sbin/losetup -d /dev/loop0
TimeoutSec=60
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
Also=systemd-udevd.service
```